# WIN32 Thread Program Issue

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

This is my first time dealing with threads.

When I run the program without the `GetCurrentThreadId()` function it executes without any issue.

When I add that line of code it still executes but crashes once it reaches the end. Why is this?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


static int tix[500];
static int done = 0;
HANDLE ghSemaphore;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction();

int main(void)
{
    DWORD threadID1, threadID2, threadID3, threadID4;
    HANDLE hThread1, hThread2, hThread3, hThread4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) //initialize array
    {
        tix[i] = 0;
    }

    ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 10, NULL);

    hThread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &threadID1);
    hThread2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &threadID2);
    hThread3 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &threadID3);
    hThread4 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &threadID4);

    //printf("The thread ID: %d.\n", threadID1);
    //printf("The thread ID: %d.\n", threadID2);
    //printf("The thread ID: %d.\n", threadID3);
    //printf("The thread ID: %d.\n", threadID4);

    if (done = 1)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread1);
        CloseHandle(hThread2);
        CloseHandle(hThread3);
        CloseHandle(hThread4);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
    {
        if (tix[j] = 0)
        {
            printf("not sold");
        }
        else if (tix[j] = 1)
        {
            printf("sold");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, 0);

    printf("current thread running : %d\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    int i = 0;
    if (done != 0) // if loop to test wether or not the array is full
    {
        while (tix[i] = 1) //traverse the array to find a open spot
        {
            i++;
        }
        tix[i] = 1;

    }
    if (i == 499) //if i is 499, set test variable to 1
    {
        done = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    ReleaseSemaphore(ghSemaphore, 1, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: The signature for your thread function is incorrect, so you are probably corrupting the stack. Don't ignore compiler warnings. Also, `if (done = 1)` and `if (tix[j] = 1)` will always be true. I suggest you master basic C before attempting multi-threading.

Comment: Your code never closes the thread handles. At the end of the function you need to WaitForMultipleObjects and ensure all threads are done executing before you close the handles. Needless to say, the variable `done` is nonsense in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: @Lundin: You do **not** have to wait for a thread to run to completion before you can close its handle. If your code doesn't need it, it can close the handle right after `CreateThread` returns.

Comment: @IInspectable It is however good practice to wait for all threads to finish before you clean up and shut down the main process.

Comment: @Lundin: That may well be the case, but it doesn't make a wrong statement right. There is no requirement to keep a thread handle around, if you don't intend to use it.

Comment: @IInspectable If you close the handles, then you can no longer wait for the threads. Which is why you have to close the handles after the WaitFor function.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, I agree on the *"It's a good idea to do X, and for that to work you cannot do Y."* part. But that doesn't make your unconditional *"You must not do Y"* statement right. Don't you think it's about time to stop beating a dead horse?

Comment: @Lundin I ended up reworking the program and removed the done variable. Gonna see how that works out. Thanks for the help everyone though

Answer (score 0):

Your thread function has incorrect signature. Thread takes one `PVOID` context argument:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  _In_ LPVOID lpParameter
);
```

Your threads could exit without releasing a semaphore. Also since you had initialized it with a value, that is greater than thread amount and never check `WaitForSingleObject` result, no synchronization is provided and multiple threads will modify a shared buffers in inconsistent manner. Even worse - nothing stops your program main thread exiting earlier, than `ThreadFunction`.

There is no return statement in the end of your thread function, so this is an undefined behavior. In fact it is a great wonder that your code even compiles. This entire approach to multithreading is incorrect and has to be remade from the scratch.

Comment: This has not been the case for a very long time. If this was the case then the windows thread pool could not work. The second half of the answer is good though.

Comment: Your remark about beginthread is like 20 years old. IIRC this was because of bugs in the Visual Studio compiler and not in the Windows API.

Comment: Well. MSDN still has this recommendation. Who am I to contradict them?)

Comment: Removed outdated info. Thanks @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Yeah MSDN still living in the past and pandering to msvc 6 users

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Your comment refers to the (now fixed) issue, where calling the CRT on a thread created using [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) produced a memory leak. This is indeed no longer the case. However, *"if a thread created using CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions"* is still true, for all I know.